# Why does my mobile WordPress menu display on the admin panel but not the site?

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, menu, bootstrap-5

The mobile menu is displayed in the backend but not in the frontend.

The theme is: Bootscore

I added the following code to my functions.php to register the mobile menu:

```
function wdm_register_mobile_menu() {
    add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
    register_nav_menus( array('mobile-menu' => __( 'Mobile Menu', 'wdm' )) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wdm_register_mobile_menu' );
```

Then I extended the functions with the following code:

```
// load the JS file
function wdm_mm_toggle_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wdm-mm-toggle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mobile-menu-toggle.js', array('jquery') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wdm_mm_toggle_scripts' );
```

Then I added the following code to the mobile-menu-toggle.js :

```
// hide or display the mobile menu

/* let's consider we want to toggle the menu displayed at 800 screen width, here's what we need to do (you can accordingly replace 800 with to a screen width you would need)..*/
function toggle() {
    if ( jQuery( window ).width() >= 800 ) {
      jQuery( '.nav.mobile-menu' ).hide();
      jQuery( '.nav.desktop-menu' ).show();
    } else {
      jQuery( '.nav.desktop-menu' ).hide();
      jQuery( '.nav.mobile-menu' ).show();
    }
}

// on page load set the menu display initially
toggle();

// toggle the menu display on browser resize
jQuery( window ).resize( function () {
    toggle();
} );
```

Then i added this code in my header-woocommerce.php in my child theme:

```
<!-- Bootstrap 5 Nav Walker Main Menu -->
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                  'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
                  'container' => false,
                  'menu_class' => '',
                  'fallback_cb' => '__return_false',
                  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="bootscore-navbar" class="navbar-nav ms-auto %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                  'depth' => 2,
                  'walker' => new bootstrap_5_wp_nav_menu_walker()
                ));

                if ( function_exists('has_nav_menu') && has_nav_menu('mobile-menu') ) {
                  wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'depth' => 6,
                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                    'container' => 'ul',
                    'menu_id' => 'main-nav',
                    'menu_class' => 'nav mobile-menu',
                    'theme_location' => 'mobile-menu'
                  ) );
                  } else {
                    echo "<ul class='nav mobile-menu'> <font style='color:red'>Mobile Menu has not been set</font> </ul>";
                  }
                ?>
```

Comment: _"my header-woocommerce.php in my child theme"_ - is that a default WooCommerce template that your child theme has overwritten, or is it something the child theme brought with it? I really can't make sense of why or how your menu should be showing in the admin area - frontend and backend usually use different template files to begin with.

Comment: Your `mobile-menu-toggle.js` should not even load when you are in the backend - when added via the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, those scripts are output on frontend pages only, you'd have to be using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook in the first place to get any scripts added to your backend.